# Is there type or interface that implements of collection and selected value?

Tags: c#, collections

I need a type that keeps track of a collection and the selected value in a collection, similar to what a list box would do.  Is there an existing (non-gui control) collection for this?  I know it's fairly simple but I would rather use Microsoft's provided type if there is one.

Basically, this is what I want:

```
interface ISelectionList<T>
{
   T Selected
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
   IList<T> Values
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is nothing like that in the .NET framework.

I would like to suggest that you build your interface a bit differently to leverage the power of inherited interfaces.

Try something like this:

```
interface ISelectionList<T> : IList<T>
{
    T Selected { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow you to still use your `ISelectionList<T>` as an `IList<T>` where needed.

Comment: Dammit, you beat me to it! ;-) +1